# Creating a Dynamic JQuery Plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins

I am learning about creating JQuery Plugins. Currently, I have a plugin that is defined as follows:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function (options) {
        var defaults = { e: 0 },
        settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        var plugin = $.myPlugin.getHtml(options.e);
        if ((plugin != null) && (plugin != undefined) && (plugin.length > 0)) {
            this.html(plugin);
        }
    };

    $.myPlugin = {
        getHtml: function (e) {
            var s = "";
            if (e == 0) {
              s = "1";
            } else {
              s = "2";
            }
            return s;
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Currently, I initialize an instance of this plugin using the following:

```
$("#myDiv").myPlugin({ e: 0 });
```

How do I add a timer to myPlugin so that every 15 seconds I can update the html of myDiv with a counter?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `setInterval`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick bit of code that you could put within the plugin to run setInterval as suggested by the comment above.  Adapt for your purposes.  Lookup setInterval for more info.

```
var counter = 0;
setInterval(function () {
   counter += 1;
   $.myPlugin.getHtml(counter)
}, 15000);
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the function syntax. If I replace $.myPlugin.getHtml(counter) with the code you've provided, will the timer get started when the plugin is initialized?

Comment: Put this code with your $.fn.myPlugin function.  Maybe at the end.  The code as I have it will run the getHtml method every 15 seconds with the counter incremented by one. If you want, you can create a different method than getHTML to use within the function.